# What is the best way to create a whois lookup?

Tags: php, dns, lookup, whois

I want add a domain registration in a website written with PHP. So I need a whois lookup service. What do I need to do? What's are its steps?

Do I need a database, API or ... ? Help me please

Comment: I made this [Whois API](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) and here's the PHP client library:[whois-api-php](https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-api-php).

Comment: If you need "domain registration" you do not need just whois. You should approach one trusted registrar of your choice, for the TLDs you need and see what kind of API they can provide for your needs.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch Hi, in the [readme.md on the github page](https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-api-php), you direct to a [link to get an API key](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) Unfortunately that one is dead. So what should we do?

Comment: Sorry, I terminated that service.

Comment: We use https://www.completeapi.com.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak to the quality of any of the following services, but here are a few offerings:

- [WhoAPI](https://whoapi.com/)
- [Hexillion Whois API](https://hexillion.com/whois)
- [DomainTools API](https://www.domaintools.com/resources/api-documentation/whois-lookup)
- [WhoisXMLAPI](https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/)